# exporting all event view to excel

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to export all event view of a calendar to excel with a people/group column that allows multiple selection in multiple lines rather inline. If not is there any possible workaround

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OOTB "Export to Excel" feature to achieve it.

[image]

Or using jQuery to achieve it. Check the article below.

[Export SharePoint List to Excel, Word, JSON, XML, SQL, CSV, TXT or PDF](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Export-SharePoint-List-to-a802fd93)